# Problem making a calculation in a monitor on the interface in Netlogo

Tags: interface, netlogo, monitor, calculation

I have a model that tracks energy levels in sheep, which I have defined as a breed. I have set up a monitor to calculate the mean energy level for the sheep, but need to consider what happens if there are no sheep at some point. I have tried numerous variations, the simplest of which is:

```
ifelse (any? sheep) ["NA"] [mean [energy] of sheep]
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting the error

> Expected reporter.

I can work around this by creating a new global variable and reporter in the code, but this seems to be a bit of a waste. Am I doing something wrong or are there limitations on what kind of calculations can be done in a monitor on the Interface? If so, where are these limitations summarized?

Answer (score 2):

Answer in three steps:

### Difference between `ifelse` and `ifelse-value`

You are getting a syntax error there because a monitor expects a reporter, but `ifelse` is made to handle commands. [The reporter version of `ifelse`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#ifelse-value) is `ifelse-value`. If you just change `ifelse` to `ifelse-value` in your example, you see that you don't get any syntax error anymore. However, you will also see that if you do so and start your model with sheep having their `energy`, the monitor will show `NA` - see next point.

### Correct use of `any?`

This happens because you are using `any?` the other way around. [As you can see](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#any), `any?` reports true if the agentset is not empty. This means that the following reporter:

```
ifelse-value (any? sheep) ["NA"] [mean [energy] of sheep]
```

will report `"NA"` when there are sheep in the model, because that is the first reporter block.

Switch to:

```
ifelse-value (any? sheep) [mean [energy] of sheep] ["NA"]
```

and you have what you want. Just as in English: "If there are any sheep, do the calculation, else, this does not apply".

In any case, this does the job but it is superflous - see next point.

### What monitors can do

Monitors are able to handle some of their reporters' runtime errors. You can simply put `mean [energy] of sheep` in your monitor and it will automatically show `N/A` when there are no sheep, without the need for you to handle the case.